# CTE not able to sum blank columns out of multiple columns

Tags: sql-server-2005, common-table-expression

I want to calculate total_revenue column for each row but cte is not doing it. I get pr column as empty for few months and have value for some of the. So i get a total_revenue where the pr column is not blank. What i am doing wrong?

```
ormonth     cc_o    cc_r      po    pr  po_o    po_r    total_orders    total_revenue
2018-06     1367    152903.89   0       44     6424.66    1411  
2018-05     10069   1086544.02  0       242    27926.02   10311 
2018-04     11208   1151114.03  0       221    26004.69   11429 
2018-01     13416   1379387.01  0       152    17023.29   13568 
2018-03     12025   1303165.8   0       197    19957.87   12222 
2018-02     12647   1252867.33  0       171    16907.52   12818 
2018-01     145     1100.43     6  121  170    1600       321                2822
```

here is the query I used:

```
with cte_Revenue as (
SELECT
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(7),Orders.OrderDate,126) as ormonth,
 COUNT(CASE WHEN Orders.paymentmethodid = 5 OR Orders.paymentmethodid = 6 THEN Orders.PaymentAmount END) as 'CC_O',
 SUM(CASE WHEN Orders.paymentmethodid = 5 OR Orders.paymentmethodid = 6 THEN Orders.PaymentAmount END) as 'CC_R',

COUNT(CASE WHEN Orders.paymentmethodid = 25 THEN Orders.paymentmethodid END) as 'PO',
 SUM(CASE WHEN Orders.paymentmethodid = 25 THEN Orders.PaymentAmount  END ) as 'PR',

COUNT(CASE WHEN Orders.paymentmethodid = 1 THEN Orders.paymentmethodid END) as 'PO_O',
 SUM(CASE WHEN Orders.paymentmethodid = 1 THEN Orders.PaymentAmount END ) as 'PO_R'
FROM
    Orders
WHERE
    Orders.OrderDate BETWEEN '01/01/2018' AND getdate() -0 AND
    Orders.OrderStatus <> 'Cancelled'
GROUP BY
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(7),Orders.OrderDate,126))
Select 
ormonth,
CC_O,
CC_R,
PO,
PR,
PO_O,
PO_R,
(CC_O+PO+PO_O) AS Total_Orders,
(CC_R+PR+PO_R) AS Total_Revenue
FROM cte_Revenue
```

Comment: Have you tried to put a case around the PR in the calculation for the Total_Revenue column?

Comment: @Steven..No I have not tried that..you mean put inside brackets?

Comment: Something like CC_R + CASE WHEN PR IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE PR END + PO_R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the PR column might be returning NULL, which would cause the calculation to not be performed.  As I mentioned in the comments, maybe a CASE statement within the SELECT would fix the issue.

```
SELECT ormonth, CC_O, CC_R, PO, PR, PO_O, PO_R, 
       (CC_O + PO + PO_O) AS Total_Orders, 
       (CC_R + CASE WHEN PR IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE PR END + PO_R) AS Total_Revenue
FROM   cte_Revenue
```

Another option would be to ensure that within the CTE, the PR column would always have a value.  Putting in ELSE statements in the CTE that would return 0, might help as well.

For example:

```
 COUNT(CASE WHEN Orders.paymentmethodid = 1 THEN Orders.paymentmethodid 
            ELSE 0 END) as 'PO_O',
 SUM(CASE WHEN Orders.paymentmethodid = 1 THEN Orders.PaymentAmount  
            ELSE 0 END ) as 'PO_R'
```

Comment: @Steven..Thank u it worked..Why didn't i think of this.